# Parsing a site where URL doesn't change with Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape [this][1] site its URL doesnt change when next page is clicked on. So, I used Selenium to click on the next page, but doing that doesnt help. As my driver keeps getting the old page even after next page is clicked on. Is there any other way to get to the next page and scrape it?

```
    from selenium import webdriver 
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
    from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 


    driver = webdriver.Safari()



        store_pages = []

    #10306 is total number of pages.
        for i in range (10306):
            Starting_url = 'site'

        driver.get(Starting_url)

        html = driver.page_source
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

        print (store_pages.append(i))

        timeout = 20

        try:
            WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='ctl00_SPWebPartManager1_g_d6877ff2_42a8_4804_8802_6d49230dae8a_lblDisclaimerMsg']")))
        except TimeoutException:
            print("Timed out waiting for page to load")
            driver.quit()

        nextpage_url = driver.find_element_by_name("ctl00$SPWebPartManager1$g_d6877ff2_42a8_4804_8802_6d49230dae8a$ctl00$imgbtnNext").click()
        timeout = 20
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element_value((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#ctl00_SPWebPartManager1_g_d6877ff2_42a8_4804_8802_6d49230dae8a > div.act_search_results > div.act_search_header'), "206113 Record(s) | Page [2 of 10306]"))

        NGO_element = driver.find_element_by_class_name("faq-sub-content exempted-result")
        NGO_name = NGO_element.find_elements_by_tag_name("h1")
        NGO_name_pancard = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("pan-id")
        NGO_data = NGO_element.find_elements_by_tag_name("ul")
        NGO_sub_data = NGO_element.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")

        for i, p, t in zip(NGO_name, NGO_name_pancard, NGO_data):
            n_name = i.text.replace(p.text, '')
            n_data = t.text 
            n_pan = p.text
            print ("Name of NGO:", n_name, "Fields of NGO:", n_data, "Pancard number:", n_pan)

        nextpage_url = driver.find_element_by_name("ctl00$SPWebPartManager1$g_d6877ff2_42a8_4804_8802_6d49230dae8a$ctl00$imgbtnNext").click()
         #timeout = 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure when you reach the next page, the content of the earlier page has become stale otherwise, you will have stale element error or get the same thing repeatedly. Try the below approach, it should get you there. The rest you can modify yourself.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get("http://www.incometaxindia.gov.in/Pages/utilities/exempted-institutions.aspx")

while True:
    for elem in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"[id^='arrowex']"))):
        print(elem.text)

    try:
        wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "ctl00_SPWebPartManager1_g_d6877ff2_42a8_4804_8802_6d49230dae8a_ctl00_imgbtnNext"))).click()
        wait.until(EC.staleness_of(elem))
    except:
        break
driver.quit()
```